# MongoDB: Timestamp collection update time

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB so I've been having difficulty making use of some of the features. I have a database and when it updates the collection, I want a timestamp to be created to give me the last time it was updated.

It's to be utilised in a Java back end for a web application to be put out onto the front end for the users to see.

I'm having problems extracting the timestamp from Mongo. Any suggestions as to how I can get that information into the Java where I can use it?

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried that is not working?

Comment: MongoDB "has no schema". So if you are expecting fields to be "magically created for you" ( rails style ) then you are basically out of luck. You either explicitly set the field to be updated in you update or create conditions, or you use something that "defines a schema" within your code. This can then wrap methods to "create things automagically" as you seem to be asking.